# AdWords Conversion tracking on a Single Page React App

Tags: google-ads, google-tag-manager, single-page-application, react-js

### Context:

In not familiar with google AdWords at all, and I don't have access to the AdWords configuration system (whatever it may be). I'm on the dev team who built a food delivery platform. The client has outsourced the marketing aspects to a marketing company.

The application is build in:

- React
- Redux
- Connected-Router
- Redux-Beacon
- GTM (for tools like GA, Floodlight, Hotjar etc)

We have a separate auth portal living on a subdomain called `auth.scoot.co.za`, which a user MUST go through at some stage (e.g ordering cant be done without an account)

The marketing team has published pay for ads on google. [image: search for south african mcdonalds delivery]

### The problem:

**Problem Summary:**

> The marketing team claims that the ads aren't being picked up as the
> source of conversion / sales on the app. From my very limited
> understanding it seems that this Ad Context is lost somehow, and by the time the sale is made
> the source of the sale is inferred as organic inside GA vs Paid Search (CPC) (see image below) [image]

**What I've seen in my testing:**

When clicking on the link in google the ad does append the gclid like below

```
https://**********/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjsTu_8jl6gIVTe7tCh1Xsw--EAAYASAAEgI5DvD_BwE
```

But when clicking on any other link in the app the url will get replaced with the relevant new url (without preserving the `gclid` query string)

```
https://**********/menu
https://**********/order-history
etc..
```

I have also seen that the following cookies are present on the app, `_gcl_aw` seems to align to the query string value that was supplied initially via the google ad link.
[image]

**Other potential relevant info:**

- I have enabled the conversion linker in GTM
- I have setup subdomain tracking

What am I missing? There doesn't seem to be a lot of info online with how to setup Google Ads correctly online within the context of a SPA app, and me not knowing marketing well enough & the marketing guys not knowing dev well enough has created some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this blog post.

https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/

In there Simo highlights that the issue is to do with the `location` being updated, this I believe is something intrinsic to SPA apps. His solution of just creating a new property in the `dataLayer` didn't work for all our application's use cases, as during some workflow of this SPA, we DO leave the single page.

Thus I ended up creating a slightly different implementation of his suggested solution. I ended up persisting the original location in session storage (as it is the most likely to be cleared out when, well.. the session ends.) See code below:

```
<script>
  if(!{{DLV - OriginalLocation}}) { 
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];  
    var _ol = document.location.protocol + '//' +  
         document.location.hostname +  
         document.location.pathname +  
         document.location.search;   
    
    var sessionItem = sessionStorage.getItem('{{Const - OriginalLocation Key}}');
    
    if(sessionItem) {    
       window.dataLayer.push({  
         originalLocation: sessionItem
       });  
    } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem("{{Const - OriginalLocation Key}}", _ol);    
      window.dataLayer.push({  
        originalLocation: _ol
      }); 
    }    
  }  
</script>
```

I then made a variable that gets connected to the GA tracking config.

```
function(){
  var sessionItem = sessionStorage.getItem('{{Const - OriginalLocation Key}}');
  if(sessionItem) {
    return sessionItem;
  }  
  return null;
}
```

Variations of the fix above (that didn't work).

- I did try to manually rebuild the original location using the existing `_gclid`, this did work, but I think it would have causes issues when we start to introduce `utm` parameters.
- I tried to make my own custom cookie, but this could result in the cookie persisting a bit too long, and then we could potentially get false ad hits (if the cookie hasn't expired and the user re-visits on the same day via another link)

Comment: could you explain in more detail?
how to create {{Const - OriginalLocation Key}} ?
we'll do the rest as Simo described?

Comment: Thats just a constant variable with a name that will get used when data gets stored in into the session Storage. e.g Its a user defined variable of type constant (in TAG manager)